# Почему не импортируется функция?

Tags: javascript

*У меня есть 2 файла (тестовых): app.js и modules.js.*

**Вот modules.js:**

```
const func = () => {
   console.log('hf,jnftn!');
}

export default func;
```

**Вот app.js:**

```
import func from './modules.js';

func();
```

**Вот index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Barba v1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="about.html">about</a>

    <script src="modules.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Я посмотрел в консоль, мне вывелась ошибка:

> Unexpected identifier 'func'. import call expects exactly one argument.

Я яндексил, гуглил, все синтаксисы перепробывал. Не работает. 
**ЧТо делать?**

Comment: Оставьте только один тег в html `<script src="app.js" type="module"></script>`.

Comment: И в него импортируйте всё остальное

Comment: @hu-fo СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ! ДОбрый человек! Здоровья счастья вам